# Setting the frontend url brakes the admin console

Tags: keycloak

I'm running keycloak in docker compose with the frontend url set to `bob`.
`bob:8080` loads the landing page, but I can't access the master realm console anymore. It redirects to `http://bob:8080/auth/bob/admin/` which is 404. Works without setting the frontend url. I'm on keycloack 15.0.1.
Where should it be?

Answer (score 4):

Ok. So the documentation wasn't that specific about the fact that you HAVE TO add /auth to the end of the frontend url. `http://bob/auth` works.
I'm leaving this here so people of the future will have a chance to find the response not answered on the official forums.